# Grow two Ubuntu partitions using unallocated space before them

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, gparted, merge

I want to merge the unallocated space with my Ubuntu partitions. I want to add 80GB more to sda7 partition and allocate the remaining space to the sda8 partition. How can I do this with GParted?

Below is a screenshot of the disk structure.

[image: Disk structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot from the installation media a select "Try Ubuntu".
2. Run GParted.
3. Using GParted:

   - Move your `/dev/sda7` partition to the left (either as far as possible, or leave some space for possible future expansion of the Windows partition `/dev/sda3`), and resize it according to the plan.
   - Then move `/dev/sda8` as far to the left as possible, and resize it to the maximum possible.